# Сортировка списка

Tags: python, сортировка

Есть список:
a = ['0 10.0.41.161', '2 10.3.4.59', '10 10.8.33.6', '3 10.3.4.155' '20 10.3.4.75', '16 10.3.4.134']

Как отсортировать список по данным 0, 2, 10, 3, 20, 16? Метод [l for l in sorted(a)] не формирует как нужно.

Comment: У sort есть параметр key. Вкуривайте его, оно то, что вам надо.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x : x[:x.index(' ')])
```

если хотите лексикографически отсортировать, а если как числа, то

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x : int(x[:x.index(' ')]))
```

Answer (score 1):

sorted по умолчанию будет сортировать как строки. а то, что там есть пробелы и цифры...
поэтому, определяем новую функцию

```
def mycmp(x,y):
    return int(x.split(' ')[0]) - int(y.split(' ')[0])
```

писано от руки, поэтому, может быть не на столько эффективно, но рабочее. Эта функция должна возвращать 0, если элементы равные, минус - если порядок неверный. Я просто делаю split по пробелу и извлекаю первый элемент.
а вот так теперь нужно сортировать
    r = sorted(a, mycmp)

если нравятся лямбды, нет проблем
    sorted(a, lambda x,y: int(x.split(' ')[0]) - int(y.split(' ')[0]))

Comment: пока писал, ответили:)

Answer (score 1):

> Как отсортировать список по данным 0, 2, 10, 3, 20, 16?

Вам нужна сортировка в произвольном порядке что-ли?

```
order = ('0', '2', '10', '3', '20', '16')
sorted(a, key=lambda i: order.index(i.split(' ')[0]) )
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за объяснения!

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется упорядочить список a в арифметическом порядке:

```
a = ['0 10.0.41.161', '2 10.3.4.59', '10 10.8.33.6', '3 10.3.4.155', '20 10.3.4.75', '16 10.3.4.134']
```

, по первым значащим символам строк, входящим в список, т.е. по символам '0', '2', '10', '3', '20', '16', то допустимо следующее решение с использованием функции вида:

```
def order(a, b):
    if int(a[:a.index(' ')]) > int(b[:b.index(' ')]):
            return 1
    elif int(a[:a.index(' ')]) < int(b[:b.index(' ')]):
            return -1
    elif int(a[:a.index(' ')]) == int(b[:b.index(' ')]):
            return 0
```

В этом случае

```
b = sorted(a, cmp = order)
```

возвращает отсортированный список b со значением:

```
['0 10.0.41.161', '2 10.3.4.59', '3 10.3.4.155', '10 10.8.33.6', '16 10.3.4.134', '20 10.3.4.75']
```